# How to create a count function for an array that maintains the time and location of the points (python)

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

I have two netcdf files which I have used to calculate the Humidex of the Houston area. From there I need to find a way to count the number of days at each lat/lon that have days that meet a certain threshold (41). I then need to plot a spatial map of the count number over the region so I can compare the number of extremely hot days a each point in the region. I've used xarray.where in order to isolate the number of days at this threshold, but when I apply a count function I lose my time and lat/lon variables, and just get an output of the total number of data points at this threshold.

humidex is a calculation of two different netcdf files, it has latitude and longitude variables
​

```
>>> hotday = xr.DataArray(humidex)
>>> hotday.where(hotday >=41)


<xarray.DataArray 'tasmax' (lat: 960, lon: 1920)>
array([[nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
       ...,
       [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan]], dtype=float32)
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) float64 -89.86 -89.67 -89.48 -89.3 ... 89.3 89.48 89.67 89.86
  * lon      (lon) float64 0.0 0.1875 0.375 0.5625 ... 359.2 359.4 359.6 359.8
    height   float64 2.0

>>>for ii in hotday:
  >>> counting=xr.DataArray.count(ii)
>>>counting

<xarray.DataArray 'tasmax' ()>
array(1920)
Coordinates:
    lat      float64 89.86
    height   float64 ...
```

I hope this makes sense, I'm still new to coding and this has really thrown me.

Comment: We'll need you to be more specific on the expected output.  If you aggregate over time, then what timestamp makes sense to preserve?  If you aggregate over position, then what lat/long data makes sense?

Comment: I expect that you will want some use of `groupby` to aggregate your items.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO. There are numerous ways to do solve your problem.

Here's one proposed method:

```
import xarray as xr
data = xr.tutorial.open_dataset('air_temperature') 

high_temps = xr.where(data > 300, 1, 0) #set all temps over 300K = 1; others to 0
summed_temps = high_temps.sum(dim='time')
```

You could then plot the heat map directly.